# Find max and min

Tags: python

I am trying to Write a Python program that requests five integer values from the user. It then prints the maximum and minimum values entered.

```
#Program to print max and min

number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
num_list = []

while (number != int(-1)):
    num_list.append(number)
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

high = max(num_list)
low = min(num_list)
```

How can I limit the number of inputs by 5?

Comment: maybe look a the size of you num_list. it will give you a stop condition for your while.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Create the number list
num_list = []
# Iterate 5 times:
# '_' means that we don't want to use this variable
# range(5) returns iterator (0,1,2,3,4) (with length=5)
for _ in range(5):
    # Get input
    # It can raise an error, I don't check it
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    # If the number is equal to -1
    if number == -1:
        # We exit from the loop
        break
    # If we didn't exit, we add number to num_list
    num_list.append(number)

high = max(num_list)
low = min(num_list)
```

You will try to get five numbers. If one of them is equal to -1, you will break from the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `while` loop

```
num_list = []
counter = 0
while counter < 5:
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if number == -1:
        break
    counter += 1
    num_list.append(number)

high = max(num_list)
low = min(num_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num_list = []
while len(num_list) < 5:
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if number == -1:
        break
    num_list.append(number)

high = max(num_list)
low = min(num_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.

```
values = str(input("Enter Five values comma(,) separted :")).split(',')
print(f'Max : {max([int(x) for x in values])}\nMin : {min([int(x) for x in values])}')
```